# spring rmi java 1.4 and java 1.5

Tags: java, spring, rmi

Is it possible to have a `rmi server` compiled with java 1.5 and a `rmi client` compiled with java 1.4 that is connecting to `rmi server`?

I am using `spring 2.5`(for client) and `spring 3.0.5RELEASE` for server.

Now I tested this but I think I did something wrong and it is not working for me...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you got error messages or stacktraces?

Comment: yes.. but I don't want to influence you with my errors :)) I really need this and I hope for a positive response :))

Comment: A stack trace wouldn't be bothersome and would likely help you get a better answer

Comment: the error I had was not from miss-compatibility.. thank you.. I was wrong.. it is possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, you'll have to ensure that you provide `Stubs`, compile with `rmic`.

This discussion provides a pretty good overview:  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1176259